how to get accurate screen size in kivy, for android
using Window.size gives me inaccurate results (it is set to (1200, 900) and even if I set Window.size to something else it remains with those values.).
I try to make an app, to be used on smartphones. And because screen sizes/quality can varey I want to use relative positioning in my app, it is easy when using pos_hint is possible and withtvhat I have no problem, the problem is with object that cant use pos_hint (to be more specific, graphics objects like ellipse or line or rectangle) so I try to use pos by multiplying Window.size[0]/[1] with the precent I would have put in pos_hint
The problem is that it works fine for the standard kivy computer 1200×900 because thats what window.size return (even after changing window.size) but once I open it on the phoneits all messed up!
does anyone know how to get accurate screen size in kivy? or at least use relative positioning to object that only use 'pos'

What are you asking here? There is no stated question and no debugging information. Please edit the question to include these things.
